# Using clang from non-default location

Tags: c++, clang

I have cloned clang from its git repository and built it as per instructions on this page: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

The repo does not lie in any default location.

I have a file `myfile.cpp` which includes `concepts` using

```
include <concepts>
```

While I am trying to call the `<path_to_llvm>/llvm/build/bin/clang -std=c++20 myfile.cpp`, it complains

```
fatal error: 'concepts' file not found
```

Since this is clang-14, I am pretty sure it has atleast partial support for concepts. Even my default clang 12.0.5 does have it.

So, most probably, I have to set some paths before calling clang executable stored in a non-default location ?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask on the [LLVM/Clang forum](https://llvm.discourse.group/c/llvm-project/clang/6). I suspect you have to initialize your default include directory paths OR make sure that there are include files in those paths.

Comment: Also, use `-v` to print those "include search paths" and check whether something is unexpected.